# Send WiFi Packets with different transmission power

Tags: linux, wifi, pcap

I have question regarding sending frames over WiFi with different transmission power. The scenario is, i want to send packets periodically with different transmission power. I know its possible to change transmission by

```
ifconfig and iw
```

but it wont help in this situation. I have a C program which send some WiFi packets using pcap. I need to send these packet with transmission power.

I hope the question is clear

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered looking at [the iwconfig source code](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/wireless-tools/iwconfig.c?rev=7473#L1242)?

Comment: Not yet..i will go through it ..Thanks a lot

Comment: @thatotherguy there another issue. why it is only possible to change tx power if it is connected to access point? 
Also i tired by changing the value in the radiotap header, but no use.#

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into "iw"?

```
iw reg set GY
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
```

iw = "manipulate wireless devices and their configuration"

reg = "regulatory agent"

set = "notify the kernel about the current regulatory domain"

Comment: ja..but that's not what i want

Comment: Alright, your original question referenced "ifconfig and iwget" and I had never heard of iwget which is why I mentioned "iw"